# Custom column in Oracle/SQL/My-Sql Query?

Tags: mysql, sql, oracle

I have database ready with data as per below screenshot, green column is customized column which I need to generate while querying data from SQL/Oracle.

> Logic: If **Actual_Completion_Date** is not an empty/null, then bring
> **Actual_Completion_Date** into **Completion_Date** else get
> **Schedule_Completion_Date** in **Completion_Date** column.

Is there any way, where I should write If statement while defining column names in SQL query without stored procedure help.

[image]

Comment: case when end logic

Comment: can you please elaborate, assume I'm new bee to query part

Comment: this is the [reference](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/case.html) to the case syntax.

Comment: COALESCE(Actual_Completion_Date,Schedule_Completion_Date)AS Completion_date

Comment: You need to clarify - is your "custom column" meant to be some sort of actual column in the table, or simply a "column" in the query output?

Comment: @EdStevens It is simply column in the query output

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If both date field contains NULL value then use simply COALESCE(). IF first one is NULL then second one value will show if it's not NULL. If first one is not null then will sshow first one value.

```
SELECT Activity_Details, Actual_Completion_Date
     , Schedule_Completion_Date
     , COALESCE(Actual_Completion_Date, Schedule_Completion_Date) AS Completion_Date
FROM tbl;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply do this in the SELECT clause of your query. For example using the IF() function like this in mysql:

```
SELECT Activity_Details, Actual_Completion_Date, Schedule_Completion_Date, IF(Actual_Completion_Date IS NOT NULL, Actual_Completion_Date, Schedule_Completion_Date) AS Completion_Date
FROM tbl;
```

The IF function takes a condition that should return True or False as the first argument. If the condition evaluates to true, the second argument is returned and if it evaluates to false, the third.

In Oracle or Microsoft SQL server you would do something similar in the SELECT clause of your query, but using CASE WHEN ... THEN ... ELSE ... END

Answer (score 0):

Oracle (and MySQL) both support *generated columns*.  That means that you can add the logic as part of the table definition.  I'm not sure if this is what you are asking for, but in Oracle, this looks like:

```
alter table t add column completion_date date generated always as
     (coalesce(Actual_Completion_Date, Schedule_Completion_Date)) virtual;
```

This would be calculated when the table is queried and available to any query that uses the table.